# Magnolia CMS - Converting a page variant to the default page

Tags: content-management-system, variant, magnolia

I have a page that has multiple variants on my Magnolia CMS. I want to convert one of those variants as the default page. I don't think there is an out-of-the-box automated solution for that. The simplest approach that I can think of is to copy the components from the new variant and paste them onto the default page but that is a tedious process as I have a lot of components on the new variant. Instead of redoing all the tasks on the default page, is there an easy way to convert a variant to the default page?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a product feature currently. We would welcome you to make a suggestion here - ideally including some details about why you want it or what problems it is causing you.
https://portal.productboard.com/magnolia/1-magnolia-roadmap/tabs/1-considering/submit-idea

Cheers, Topher

Answer (score 0):

> The simplest approach that I can think of is to copy the components from the new variant and paste them onto the default page but that is a tedious process

[CopyUtil](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/ENTERPRISE/repos/personalization/browse/magnolia-personalization-core/src/main/java/info/magnolia/personalization/util/CopyUtil.java#47) might help with that (you probably need to remove the existing nodes first).